Sliders and Observables in Julia GLMakie
I have troubles in understanding which syntax is currently correct to make interactive objects in Julia with GLMakie. I wrote a very easy code as an example to show what I understood and that it doesn't work:
using GLMakie, Makie
using Observables, Colors

x = Observable(4)
y = Observable(0)
raggio = Observable(3)
raggio1_piccolo = Observable(6)
raggio2_piccolo = Observable(6)
offsett = Observable(pi)

fig = Figure(size = (800, 800))
display(fig)
ax = Axis(fig[1,1], title = "cose che ruotano")

x_sl = Slider(fig[2,1], value = x[], range = 0:0.01:10)
y_sl = Slider(fig[3,1], value = y[], range = 0:0.01:10)
raggio_sl = Slider(fig[4,1], value = raggio[], range = 0:0.01:10)
offsett_sl = Slider(fig[5,1], value = offsett[], range = 0:0.01:3.14)

c1 = arc!(Point2f(0, 0), 1, 0, 2pi, color = "gray50")

function fai_cerchio!(ax, center, radius, phase, color)
    arc!(ax, center, radius, phase, 2pi + phase, color)
end

@lift begin
    arc!(ax, Point2f($x, $y), $raggio, $offsett, 2pi+ $offsett, color = "gray50")
end


the circles don't react to the sliders values.
Tried various tutorials but their syntax is old.

There's a few things going on here, but it's mostly that you don't have the Observable objects linked to the listeners for the sliders correctly. Here's a snippet that should do what you're looking for (with a couple minor adjustments - I've removed the offset/phase slider because it doesn't do anything if the arcs are all circles, and I've changed the window size to be more square).
using GLMakie
fig = Figure(resolution = (800, 800))
ax = Axis(fig[1, 1], title = "cose che ruotano")

x_sl = Slider(fig[2, 1], range = 0:0.01:10, startvalue = 4)
y_sl = Slider(fig[3, 1], range = 0:0.01:10, startvalue = 0)
radius_sl = Slider(fig[4, 1], range = 0:0.01:10, startvalue = 3)

center = lift(x_sl.value, y_sl.value) do x, y
    Point2f(x, y)
end

radius = lift(radius_sl.value) do r
    r
end

arc!(center, radius, 0, 2π, color = "gray50")
fig

If you want to have a SliderGrid object instead, then you'd swap out the Slider definitions and lift functions with the following:
sg = SliderGrid(
    fig[2, 1],
    (label = "x", range = 0:0.01:10, format = "{:.1f}", startvalue = 4),
    (label = "y", range = 0:0.01:10, format = "{:.1f}", startvalue = 0),
    (label = "radius", range = 0:0.01:10, format = "{:.1f}", startvalue = 3),
    width = 750
)

sliderobservables = [s.value for s in sg.sliders]

center = lift(sliderobservables...) do slvalues...
    Point2f(slvalues[1], slvalues[2])
end

radius = lift(sliderobservables...) do slvalues...
    slvalues[3]
end


Thank you very much. But now how can I change the layout of the Sliders? I saw that it's possible with SlideGrid but clearly the latter doesn't make me work properly with Observables and listeners. I would like to add labels and to show the actual value the slider is set on

To use SliderGrid you would swap out the Slider definitions and lift functions. I've edited the answer to have that as an option.
